# Variable not working in boolean

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```
var colors = generateColors();
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".squares");
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");
var pickedColor = pickColor();
var numSquares = 6;

assignColors();

function assignColors(){
    for (i = 0; i < numSquares; i++){
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }
};

function generateColors(){
    //Create arr
    var arr = [];
    //Create Colors and Push Them to arr
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        //Create Colors
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() *256);
        var g = Math.floor(Math.random() *256);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() *256);
        var color = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
        //Push to arr
        arr.push(color);
    };
    //Return arr
    return arr;
};


function pickColor(){
    //Create Random Number
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    //Display Color
    colorDisplay.textContent = colors[random];
    //Return Picked Color
    return colors[random];

};
```

So I want to use the variable `numSquares` because it's more practical in my code. But it only works in the function `assignColors()`. I would like to replace the 6 in the 2 other functions by `numSquares`, but it's not working.

Comment: "but it's not working"... Please tell us what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `generateColors()` and `pickColor()` before you assign a value to the variable `numSquares`, so the other functions don't yet know about the value due to how hoisting works. Move the variable up to the first line and it should work.

```
var numSquares = 6;
var colors = generateColors();
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".squares");
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");
var pickedColor = pickColor();
```

Plus, I'm not sure how this variable is related to a boolean. It appears to me that in `generateColors()` and `assignColors()` it functions as a conditional, and then in `pickColors()` as just a number. Then you're returning stuff other than a boolean from these functions.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are calling generateColors() and pickColors() before the numSquare gets a value assigned. 
Javascript does the hoisting that is once it goes through the whole code assigning the variables, objects or functions to the scopes but then it interprets line by line and assigning value.